# Use `If` to create new list from old

Tags: functions

I'm trying to use `If` and `AppendTo` to create a list by imposing conditions on an initial list.  And I'm getting an error that *"the expression n cannot be used as a part specification."*

```
X = Tuples[{0, 1}, 4];
B = {};
If[Length[Subsets[X][[n]]] = 2, 
   AppendTo[B, Mod[Total[Subsets[X][[n]]], 2]], {n, 1, 100}
  ];
```

There must be a very simple mistake I'm making here right?  Obviously, the elements of `Subsets[X]` are subsets of the set `X`.  So I'm trying to select those of length 2, and then record that simple expression in a new list.

Comment: There might be better way to do this without using appendto. But first you need to find the `=` to make it `==` in `Length[Subsets[X][[n]]] = 2` And also you need to use `Table`. Something like this `Table[If[Length[Subsets[X][[n]]] == 2, 
  AppendTo[B, Mod[Total[Subsets[X][[n]]], 2]]
  ],  {n, 1, 100} ]` but again, this slow

Comment: Given your initial X, what are you trying to get?  And, I presume you have seen that Subsets may take an argument so you could use Subsets[X,{2}] to get all subsets of X with length 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Mod[Total /@ Subsets[X, {2}], 2]
```

If you really only want to consider the first 100, you can use `MapIndexed` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
B2 = Mod[Total[Subsets[X, {2}], {2}], 2]
```

Compare with `B`

```
B == B2[[;; Length@B]]
```

> True

where `B` is obtained from corrected version of your code:

```
X = Tuples[{0, 1}, 4];
B = {};
Do[If[Length[Subsets[X][[n]]] == 2, 
   AppendTo[B, Mod[Total[Subsets[X][[n]]], 2]]], {n, 1, 100}];
```